# What makes a question in Spanish rhetorical?

Tags: preguntas

In German, the placement or usage of single words shifts the meaning of a rhetorical question, in English, additionally distinct marker phrases are common for this purpose.

Are there specific terms/phrases or grammatical structures that make a question including a statement rhetorical in Spanish?

For example, the statement and question is

> Has the growth of the Roman Empire forced its own decline?

How would you formulate this question using Spanish terms/grammar to denote/imply to a non historian that the statement

- is true
- is wrong
- is uncertain, so you don't want to express any rhetorical meaning (I take this case also as not everyone picks up a question immediately as rhetorical, but as a real question)

I mean especially more subtle ways (single terms/grammar shifting the meaning completely, no use of subordinate clauses and direct addressing of the audience) as

> We all know that the growth ... decline, aren't we?

Your questions should differ in as few terms/grammatical structures as possible, but still clearly shift the rhetorical meaning between the 3 cases, so I can see how this can be done in an eloquent and subtle way in Spanish.

Comment: To add more, you aren't forced to use "acaso" for rhetorical questions, they are normally identified by context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Acaso** is a useful word for this purpose.

Given this non-rhetorical translation:

> ¿Forzó el crecimiento del Imperio Romano su propia destrucción?

We could make it rhetorical and imply it's wrong:

> ¿Acaso forzó el crecimiento del Imperio Romano su propia destrucción?

Or right:

> ¿Acaso no forzó el crecimiento del Imperio Romano su propia destrucción?

Answer (score 1):

An almost literal translation of your example rhetorical sentence as

> Todos sabemos que el crecimiento del imperio romano forzó su propia destrucción, ¿o no?

However, it is unclear whether the doubt is placed on the *knowledge* of the fact or the *truth* of the fact.